# Importing 3d model to Direct3D 11 Example

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, directx-11, direct3d11, 3d-model

I'm building an WP8 app with Direct3D 11, and need to load 3dModel.

I know how to load it in XNA, but XNA is not valid for WP8 :|

I need an example of how to load a 3d model in Direct3D 11.

Comment: To be honest with you, I would just develop a OBJ importer myself. This will give you great experience and it's actually pretty fun. Download a couple 3D Modelers and see how each one exports their OBJ format so you can cover a wide range of them. Of course this would be a side project but can pay off in the end because you will be able to control exactly what/how things go into your engine.

Answer (score 2):

[Wavefront OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) is a very simple and widely supported format for static 3D models. Writing a cusom importer is not difficult.

I have written a [Wavefront Importer for C#](http://pastebin.com/mya86Frj). It covers the most basic features of OBJ files (sub meshes; vertex positions, normals and texture coordinates). I do not guarantee that any of this works, it should just serve as an example on how to implement a custom mesh importer. I am using SlimDX's `Vector` types. You can replace them with vectors from your framework of choice.

Comment: but I need to write it with C++!
Windows Phone Direct3D Project!

Comment: Well yes, you would have to port it yourself. As I said, it should simply serve as an example for working with the OBJ format.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 is able to load FBX and OBJ files itself and compiles them to CMO format.

For reading CMO format and every other things you can use the sample below.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Visual-Studio-3D-Starter-455a15f1